# Unable to ignore Arqade tags in iOS app

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app, ignored-tags

For some reason, I am unable to add tags from Arqade to my "ignored tags" list using the iOS app.

Clicking once will favorite the tag as usual. Clicking it a second time will briefly show the "ignored" symbol before reverting to the default non-filled star.

[image: Me trying to ignore Naruto]

Bizarrely, this issue only seems to happen on Arqade in the iOS app. Ignoring tags from my desktop will work as expected.

- App Version: 1.6.5.4
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)